# How do I delete a tag?

Tags: support, tags

Oopsies, I accidentally created a [para](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/para) while I was trying to search if  [paragraphs](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paragraphs) existed, while editing a question.

How can I delete the tag I created?

How come there is no [paragraphs](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paragraphs)? Is it OK to make one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the tag from the question. The tag itself will be deleted in 24 hours, if there aren't any questions using it. If the tag is used from a question, it will be deleted in a month (if I recall correctly).

If you find more questions using the tag you created, just remove it, or replace it with the correct tag.

Comment: Ok, great, I already removed it from the Q.

Comment: What about creating a paragraphs tag? is that ok?

Comment: If you find it necessary, add it to a question. I noticed it was used for text paragraphs, so maybe you should make it clear in the tag wiki what the tag is not for.